# Use window function on 2 columns, one ascending and the other descending

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to have a column, the row_number(), based on 2 columns in an existing dataframe using PySpark. I'd like to have the order so one column is sorted ascending, and the other descending.

I've looked at the documentation for window functions, and couldn't find anything in PySpark here either.

Comment: Isn't it ironical to sort a dataframe in ascending and descending both?

Comment: Not at all. @pissall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df.withColumn('rowNum', F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('partitioncol').orderBy(F.asc('col1'), F.desc('col2'))))
```